# How do I get my background image to loop forever?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I got the background image to move but it doesn't repeat. It goes back to the grey background after going through the background once. How do I get the background to repeat forever. This is the code I have so far. This is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDEud.png Im using swift in xcode. Thank you.

```
   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // Background
    background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(background)

    // loop Background Image

    doAction1()

    }

     //loop background image 

     func loopBackground() {
     let moveToBottom = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 5000 - self.frame.size.height -                
     background.size.height, duration: 100.0)

     let removeTheNode = SKAction.removeFromParent()
     let moveAndRemoveBackground = SKAction.sequence([moveToBottom, removeTheNode])
     background.runAction(moveAndRemoveBackground)

     }


    //background repeat action

    func doAction1() {
    let generateBackground = SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.runBlock(self.loopBackground),
    SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])
    let endlessAction1 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(generateBackground)
    runAction(endlessAction1)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think it depends on what you are trying to do with the background.

The best thing to do in this situation would be decide when you need another background to be displaced. Basically if the user is panning the screen (moving it) then you will need to add another background once the user has reached the end of the first. As an added bonus, if they are only able to scroll in one direction you really only need 2 background nodes. Place them side by side, then once the user is well passed the first move it in front of the second, and vice versa. If they can move the screen in any direction having one in each direction (top left, top centre, top right, middle left, middle centre, middle right, bottom left, bottom centre, and bottom right) couldn't hurt, and reposition them all by making whichever node the user is within the new middle centre position.

On the other hand I highly suggest implementing a technique known as parallaxing. I would explain but I am fairly knew with it and know that I could not do it justice, so I would urge you to read: [RayWenderlich Space Shooter Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49625/sprite-kit-tutorial-space-shooter) which does an excellent job at explaining parallaxing with examples. The examples are using Spritekit but the technique is most definitely transferable.

I hope that helps, I am not adept with Swift so I am sorry that I could not provide you with example code.